# Random.Range always returns same value

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make a small simulation of traveling salesman in Unity C# and I can't get through this, my code looks right but start and nxtCity vectors always result in the same position, I really can't understand why, could any of you help?

cities is the number of total cities

positions is the array of cities taken from cities generator
these two values are right in unity editor

Here the code:

```
void Start()
{
    positions = cam.GetComponent<citiesGene>().positions;
    cities = cam.GetComponent<citiesGene>().cities;
    Debug.Log(rand);
    start = positions[Random.Range(0, cities)];
    transform.position = start;
    StartCoroutine(ChooseCity());
}

IEnumerator ChooseCity()
{
    
    while (true)
    {
        nxtCity = positions[Random.Range(0, cities)];
        arrive = false;
        StartCoroutine(GoTo(nxtCity));
        while (arrive == false)
        {
            yield return new WaitForFixedUpdate();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I know this is weird, but I've recently had the same issue.
Here are things to try:
- Make sure Cities isn't 0 or 1

Here is the other one:
- Assign the random.range to a variable first and then use it. I don't know why but  that fixed it for me for some reason.

Comment: What is the exact value of `cities`?

Comment: `nxtCity vectors always result in the same position` What position?

Comment: Please show your Inspector of `citiesGene` .. what values do you have in  `cities` and `positions` ?

Comment: hi guys thanks, cities value is 6, positions value is randomly generated every time i start game, positions is a Vector2[] full of random coords, I've checked it generates correctly

Answer (score 3):

Unity's Random.Range with (int, int) overload (NOT float, float) generates random number in range [min; max), max is exclusive, so if you call `var randomInt = Random.Range(0, 1)` result will be always 0. `var randomInt = Random.Range(0, 2)` would be 0 or 1, e.t.c

Comment: That won't matter. If he has 1 City then it will always be `0`. Which will be it's index value. So it is selecting the correct one.

Comment: Description from Unity Random (int, int) returns a random int within [minInclusive..maxExclusive). That means the returned value muss smaller than the max value.

Comment: @user15119845 correct, that is why I gave an example

Comment: cities number is 6, not 0 or 1

Comment: @XEDGit then you should make sure you are looking for right thing. You have Debug.Log(rand) but it's not new random value, may be this is confusing. To check it up you can save random result into variable and print it before use